# Creating an instance of HttpPostedFile with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to create an instance of HttpPostedFile with Reflection.

I tried:

```
var obj = (HttpPostedFile)typeof(HttpPostedFile).GetConstructor(
                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                 null, Type.EmptyTypes, null).Invoke(null);

var obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HttpPostedFile)
           , BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
           , null
           , new object[] { }
           , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

But both of them do not work.

Update: apparently the internal constructor looks like this:

```
internal HttpPostedFile(string filename, string contentType, Stream stream)
```

I tried this but without success:

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream(b.blob);
//var httpPostedFile = new HttpPostedFile();
Type[] parameters = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(Stream) };

var obj = (HttpPostedFile)typeof(HttpPostedFile).GetConstructor(
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
      null, parameters, null)
      .Invoke(new object[] { "filename", "image/jpeg", s });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go another route. Just add one more level of abstraction: create a `IHttpPostedFile` interface with all the members you need and use that both in your code and in tests. When you have this interface, you have two ways to go: you can either use duck typing to "cast" `IHttpPostedFile` to standard `HttpPostedFile` or you can implement this interface in your own class which will forward calls to an aggregated instance of `HttpPostedFile` class.

Answer (score 1):

HttpPostedFile class expects an instance of HttpInputStream class not a MemeoryStream. HttpInputStream again is an internal class so you need to create this using reflection. Do you really need to do this?