# How to instantiate a HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, reflection, file-upload

I'm trying to communicate with a system which I have no control over, however one of its methods takes in a HttpPostedFile were in my code I have a byte array. Does anybody have an example of instantiating a HttpPostedFile as I know its constructor is internal?

The best I've found is [Creating an instance of HttpPostedFile with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920977/creating-an-instance-of-httppostedfile-with-reflection) which uses reflection, however they were steered into another direction which I can't take because I am unable to modify the third party systems method signature.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is really really hacky code, but the following seems to work for me:

```
public HttpPostedFile ConstructHttpPostedFile(byte[] data, string filename, string contentType) {
  // Get the System.Web assembly reference
  Assembly systemWebAssembly = typeof (HttpPostedFileBase).Assembly;
  // Get the types of the two internal types we need
  Type typeHttpRawUploadedContent = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent");
  Type typeHttpInputStream = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpInputStream");

  // Prepare the signatures of the constructors we want.
  Type[] uploadedParams = { typeof(int), typeof(int) };
  Type[] streamParams = {typeHttpRawUploadedContent, typeof (int), typeof (int)};
  Type[] parameters = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeHttpInputStream };

  // Create an HttpRawUploadedContent instance
  object uploadedContent = typeHttpRawUploadedContent
    .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, uploadedParams, null)
    .Invoke(new object[]{data.Length, data.Length});

  // Call the AddBytes method
  typeHttpRawUploadedContent
    .GetMethod("AddBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Invoke(uploadedContent, new object[] {data, 0, data.Length});

  // This is necessary if you will be using the returned content (ie to Save)
  typeHttpRawUploadedContent
    .GetMethod("DoneAddingBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Invoke(uploadedContent, null);

  // Create an HttpInputStream instance
  object stream = (Stream)typeHttpInputStream
    .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, streamParams, null)
    .Invoke(new object[] {uploadedContent, 0, data.Length});

  // Create an HttpPostedFile instance
  HttpPostedFile postedFile = (HttpPostedFile)typeof(HttpPostedFile)
    .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, parameters, null)
    .Invoke(new object[] {filename, contentType, stream});

  return postedFile;
}
```

Comment: @paracycle - when calling .Save(filePath) on the returned HttpPostedFile - I get an empty image.  Any idea why?

Comment: @wilsjd: It's been too long since I've last looked into this. The .NET platform code might have changed considerably since then. I advise you check out the new code (using Reflector, or similar) and make the appropriate changes.

Comment: If you need to save the HttpPostedFile you also need to call the DoneAddingBytes method:
`typeHttpRawUploadedContent.GetMethod("DoneAddingBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(uploadedContent, null);`

Comment: @sundog Thank you, updated the sample with your code.

Comment: This is really useful for unit tests and saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: Brilliant. Ported to VB.NET:

Answer (score 7):

you can try

```
 var constructorInfo = typeof(HttpPostedFile).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)[0];
 var obj = (HttpPostedFile)constructorInfo
           .Invoke(new object[] { "filename", "image/jpeg", null });
```

`obj` would of type `HttpPostedFile` .I'm setting the last parameter to null but it has to be a HttpInputStream though.