# Is there a way to get an httppostedfile WITHOUT using the fileuplaod control?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, httppostedfile

I have a class that needs an System.Web.HttpPostedFile object.

In most cases this is obtained when the user uploads a pic.  However, in cases where they don't I need to pass a default image to the class.

But how do I populate the HttpPostedFile property if I'm not using the fileupload control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to instantiate a HttpPostedFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514715/how-to-instantiate-a-httppostedfile)

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** select a file from the users machine for them.  The ONLY way for a file to be selected and transferred from a client computer to your web app is if you use the `input type="file"` tag (which is what the file control wraps) and let THEM select a file.

What you CAN do is detect on post back whether they transferred a file to you or not.  If they haven't then you can use a file local to the SERVER to use instead; however, this isn't going to come through the posted file area.

As far as reasons why not: security, plain and simple.

Comment: I believe your second paragraph is what OP was looking to do. My interpretation of the question is that he wants to simulate the upload with a server side image to reuse the upload code. I give him the benefit of the doubt and believe he's not hoping that his default image is on every client machine that'll visit his site and that it's server side.

Comment: Corey, your description is correct. I want to use a default image in the server.

Comment: @KoolMok: see the comment to the original question.  It has a link to code that does what you want.