# HttpPostedFileBase convert to HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, .net

Is there possibility to convert `HttpPostedFileBase to HttpPostedFile`, i tried searching SO questions, I could only find just opposite situation `HttpPostedFile` to `HttpPostedFileBase`...

Tried reading: 
http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files

He states "In some cases we need to convert `HttpPostedFileBase` to `HttpPostedFile` and we can achieve that using the `HttpPostedFileWrapper`.", so how could I do that?

Please do not tell me to use `HttpPostedFileBase`, because I am using DevExpress framework `UploadedFile` class which only accept `HttpPostedFile` in its constructor.

I tried doing like this, but do not know what else should I write `HttpPostedFile`

```
HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;

for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    var file = files.Get(i);
}
```

Thanks for Your time and help in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this post.  It basically suggests that you're not getting anything from the HttpPostedFile that you don't from HttpPostedFileBase and there is no value in casting it.  Could that be right?

Comment: Of course, but i need still to convert it to HttpPostedFile, since i can only pass this instance to my UploadedFile constructor, there is no possibility to pass HttpPostedFileBase... I know I am not getting anything from this convertion, but in my situation i get something :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of my question looks like this:

```
        List<UploadedFile> uploadedFiles = new List<UploadedFile>();

        var files = Request.Files;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = files.Get(i);
            var constructorInfo = typeof(HttpPostedFile).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)[0];
            var obj = (HttpPostedFile)constructorInfo
                      .Invoke(new object[] { file.FileName, file.ContentType, file.InputStream });


            uploadedFiles.Add(new UploadedFile(obj));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This post seems to do what you are looking for.  You have to get at the byte array inside the `HttpPostedFileBase`, but it should do the trick:

[How to instantiate a HttpPostedFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514715/how-to-instantiate-a-httppostedfile)

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot, did like Bala R suggested.

Comment: Word - Glad that helped

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Convert data(HttpPostedFileBase) to byte data
step 2 : convertthat byte data to HttpPostedFile by this

```
public HttpPostedFile ConstructHttpPostedFile(byte[] data, string filename, string contentType)
{
    // Get the System.Web assembly reference
    Assembly systemWebAssembly = typeof(HttpPostedFileBase).Assembly;
    // Get the types of the two internal types we need
    Type typeHttpRawUploadedContent = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent");
    Type typeHttpInputStream = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpInputStream");

    // Prepare the signatures of the constructors we want.
    Type[] uploadedParams = { typeof(int), typeof(int) };
    Type[] streamParams = { typeHttpRawUploadedContent, typeof(int), typeof(int) };
    Type[] parameters = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeHttpInputStream };

    // Create an HttpRawUploadedContent instance
    object uploadedContent = typeHttpRawUploadedContent
      .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, uploadedParams, null)
      .Invoke(new object[] { data.Length, data.Length });

    // Call the AddBytes method
    typeHttpRawUploadedContent
      .GetMethod("AddBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .Invoke(uploadedContent, new object[] { data, 0, data.Length });

    // This is necessary if you will be using the returned content (ie to Save)
    typeHttpRawUploadedContent
      .GetMethod("DoneAddingBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .Invoke(uploadedContent, null);

    // Create an HttpInputStream instance
    object stream = (Stream)typeHttpInputStream
      .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, streamParams, null)
      .Invoke(new object[] { uploadedContent, 0, data.Length });

    // Create an HttpPostedFile instance
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = (HttpPostedFile)typeof(HttpPostedFile)
      .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, parameters, null)
      .Invoke(new object[] { filename, contentType, stream });

    return postedFile;
}
```