# Google Drive upload file from localhost hardisk, OOM issues due to HttpPostedFile

Tags: google-drive-api

This is web application, try to upload file in folder to Google Drive, I had done all the setting at Google console to get the credentials. It only work for smaller file, file size more than 200MB will hit OOM error.  What should I do?

For the web config, I had set

```
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="99999999" />
<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
```

After i get the Authorize from google at page load, i try to loop the directory to get the files.

```
protected string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Yeep\Desktop\GoogleDrive");
```

After loop each of the file I will create FileStream / ReadAllBytes I had try 2 way.

```
      foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = null;

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dir, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {

                        buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                        fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                    }
//byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dir); //or this way
    }
```

After loop through the file, to read all the bytes, I will run [this](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/212966/Upload-file-to-Google-Drive-directly-from-Folder-Directory-without-using-FileUpload-control-in-ASPNet/) / [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514715/how-to-instantiate-a-httppostedfile).

```
Session["File"] = ConstructHttpPostedFile(buffer, fileName);
```

When Create an HttpRawUploadedContent instance it hit OOM, how to solve or got any other method?

Comment: sorry that question is to broad try reading about authentication and come back https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth

Comment: I have finish set on Google Developers Console. to Enable API Drive, create OAuth Client ID, and set Authorized redirect URIs. pls advanced thx~

Comment: What language are you using and show the code for your insertFile method.

Comment: @DaImTo the current issues i face is out of memory when upload the large file to google drive, I'm referring this treat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514715/how-to-instantiate-a-httppostedfile . when Create an HttpRawUploadedContent instance it hit OutOfMemory error.

Comment: @DaImTo pls advice, thank you very much.