# LocalFile cast as httppostedfile

Tags: c#, httppostedfile

I have a dll to which I have no source code. This has a method that accepts httppostedfile as an input. I wanted to pass a local file stream to this method.

Is it possible somehow to convert the local file stream or bytes to httppostedfile format? An explicit castings does not work.

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own conversion code.

Comment: This topic was discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920977/creating-an-instance-of-httppostedfile-with-reflection

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514715/how-to-instantiate-a-httppostedfile

Comment: 2nd link solved the problem. Thank you.